# Process Array contents

Tags: 7, database

I've done a database query which returns the results in the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [field_latitude_value] => 25.2000000000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [field_latitude_value] => 51.9456801568 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [field_latitude_value] => 51.9471747475 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [field_latitude_value] => 51.9471218425 ) )
```

How do I process this information so I get just the values instead of the added keys? I.e a list of said values.

I'm currently using the following code, which gives me a recoverable fatal error:

```
<?php

$query = db_query('SELECT field_latitude_value FROM {field_data_field_latitude}')->fetchAll();


print_r($query); 
foreach($query as $value){
    echo $value;
};?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fetchAll(), try [fetchCol()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementBase%3A%3AfetchCol/7), like this:

`$latitude_values = db_query("SELECT field_latitude_value FROM {field_data_field_latitude}")->fetchCol();`